# LoadError: cannot load such file -- i18n/core_ext/hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler, rails-i18n

I am working on multiple projects, when I switch from one project to another, compile the assets using:

```
➜ rails assets:precompile
```

Ruby: 2.7.5
Rails: 6.0

What I get is:

```
/Users/luqman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/net-protocol-0.2.1/lib/net/protocol.rb:68: warning: previous definition of ProtocRetryError was here
/Users/luqman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/protocol.rb:206: warning: already initialized constant Net::BufferedIO::BUFSIZE
/Users/luqman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/net-protocol-0.2.1/lib/net/protocol.rb:214: warning: previous definition of BUFSIZE was here
/Users/luqman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/protocol.rb:503: warning: already initialized constant Net::NetPrivate::Socket
/Users/luqman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/net-protocol-0.2.1/lib/net/protocol.rb:541: warning: previous definition of Socket was here
rails aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- i18n/core_ext/hash
/Users/luqman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:17:in `require'
/Users/luqman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:17:in `require'
/Users/luqman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
/Users/luqman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
/Users/luqman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
/Users/luqman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/chewy-7.1.0/lib/chewy.rb:17:in `<main>'
/Users/luqman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
/Users/luqman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
/Users/luqman/Desktop/techdots-projects/ccc/config/application.rb:7:in `<main>'
/Users/luqman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
/Users/luqman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
/Users/luqman/Desktop/techdots-projects/ccc/Rakefile:4:in `<main>'
/Users/luqman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/railties-6.0.6.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:22:in `block in perform'
/Users/luqman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/railties-6.0.6.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
/Users/luqman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/railties-6.0.6.1/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
/Users/luqman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/railties-6.0.6.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
/Users/luqman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
/Users/luqman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

The problem seems to be of the i18n gem. I have even tried updating the bundler. But still getting this issue.

Even running the full trace doesn't gives me anything.

The i18n gem used is -> `i18n (>= 0.7, < 2)`

The chewy gem seems to be a problem

`/Users/luqman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/chewy-7.1.0/lib/chewy.rb:17:in`'`

Comment: looks like i18n doesn't have a hash extension any more. https://github.com/toptal/chewy/issues/832 - might want to add the versions of the gems that are dependent on it

Comment: I have already tried it, but it doesn't works. The PR explains updating the version of chewy gem. Updating it gives the same error.

Comment: add the versions of the gems that are dependent on i18n to your question

Answer (score 0):

So got it fixed by cleaning all the global and local gems by using:
`gem uninstall -aIx`

Created gemsets for each project and separate gems for each project. `Bundle install`  all the gems.

The problem here was some gems were conflicting. Even on removing the gems, it wasn't being removed completely.

I hope this helps!